# Set variable to ternary

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ternary-operator

I'm trying to render a partial within a view. When calling the render I'm passing :locals correctly. However, when trying to set the local variable in the partial view to a ternary, the 'else' logic of the statement does not get passed.

> @local_var = passed_var ? passed_var : ''

The ||= operator will not work in this instance for what I'm trying to achieve.

> @local_var = 'wrapping_text_open' + passed_var + 'wrapping_text_close' ||= ''

Comment: Why can't you do `passed_var ||= ""` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never use this, but you could do

```
local_var = (defined? passed_var) ? passed_var : ""

local_var = (defined? passed_var) ? 'wrapping_text_open' + passed_var + 'wrapping_text_close' : ''
```

Why use an instance variable?

Comment: I'm passing variables around for dynamic partials. Thanks, this was what I needed.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Instance variables are required for my case because I'm using nested partials. The views need to be dynamic by passing variables to multiple layered partials.

Comment: I dont remember ever having to do that. You can probably pass the variables through all the layers as local variables. But if instance variables works for you...